# PVRTC textures on iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

Is there any way to make [PVRTC textures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PVRTC) work on the iPhone Simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a problem why PVR textures did not work neither on simulator nor iphone.
Before drawing it's necessary to set up parameter GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER. For example, 
`glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);`

Answer (score 2):

According to [this forum thread](http://www.idevgames.com/forum/showthread.php?t=17185): yes, the simulator supports PVRTC-format compressed textures.